# Maintain relationship in derived type in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-2.1

I am facing some problem to maintain the relationship in derived types and query them using LINQ. Please consider the following scenario. Let's say I have the below hierarchy:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DocType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyDoc : Document
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDoc : Document
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

That means I have a document object and the owner of the document can be any company or any person so I create 2 derived document company doc & person doc.

My question is, is it ok to maintain a relationship like this way, if not then what is the best approach to maintain this kind of hierarchy?

In ef core 2.1 I can handle this hierarchy using TPH. But If I want to get all the document along with the owner what will be the linq query. I have tried with below one but it does not work.

```
var doc = (from d in _context.Set<Document>()
            join c in _context.Company on (d as CompanyDoc).CompanyId equals c.Id into cd
            from cdoc in cd.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join c in _context.Person on (d as PersonDoc).PersonId equals c.Id into pd
            from pdoc in pd.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new {
                d.Id,
                d.Name,
                Owner = cdoc.Name != null ? cdoc.Name : pdoc.Name
            }).ToList()
```

Can you please help me by sharing your thoughts. Please take this as a hypothetical example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating the query. EF Core is quite clever on how it handles Table per hierarchy (TPH) queries. By using the abstract class as the `DbSet<T>` property you can access all the types, and filter out what you want.

So, in your example the DbContext would contain a property `public DbSet<Document> Documents { get ; set; }` and the following queries would work.

```
//This returns all the documents - each document is of the correct type
//e.g PersonDocument or CompanyDocument
var allDocs = context.Documents.ToList();

//This would only return PersonDocuments - change the type for other versions
var personDocs = context.Documents.OfType<PersonDocument>().ToList();
```

EF Core does all the hard work to get the correct data and type for you. It's pretty nice to use.

*PS. If you have my book [Entity Framework Core in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/entity-framework-core-in-action?a_aid=su4utaraxuTre8tuthup&a_bid=4cef27ce) then I cover TPH in section 7.8.2, especially page 201.*